# Help translate handwritten paintings (calligraphy)

Tags: calligraphy, haiku

[image: Second]

Hi, I would be very happy if someone could help me desipher the calligraphy in this painting.
What I've concluded so far:
It is a Haiku and
水仙 = Daffodil

Much appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a traditional cursive text that reads:

> 水仙の
> 處を
> 得た()り
> 庭の
> 隅

It seems to be meant as [this haiku](http://home.e-catv.ne.jp/miyoshik/siki%20saloon/saloon17.html) by [正岡子規](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masaoka_Shiki):

> 水仙**も**処を得たり庭の隅
> A narcissus finally finds its place — a corner of yard

but I have no idea why there is a particle different.

The final seals read 慧石 in [seal script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_script), which seems to be the writer's pen name, though I don't know if s/he is somebody famous.

Comment: Thank you @broccoli forest! I'm not high enough level to up vote, but you have my sincere gratitude :)